# Not able to save pyspark iforest model using pyspark

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, mlflow

Using `iforest` as described here: https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest
But `model.save()` is throwing exception:

> Exception:
> scala.NotImplementedError: The default jsonEncode only supports string, vector and matrix. org.apache.spark.ml.param.Param must override jsonEncode for java.lang.Double.

Followed the code snippet mentioned under "Python API" section on mentioned git page.

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
import os
import tempfile
from pyspark_iforest.ml.iforest import *

col_1:integer
col_2:integer
col_3:integer

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=in_cols, outputCol="features")
featurized = assembler.transform(df)

iforest = IForest(contamination=0.5, maxDepth=2)
model=iforest.fit(df)

model.save("model_path")
```

`model.save()` should be able to save model files.

Below is the output dataframe I'm getting after executing `model.transform(df)`:

```py
col_1:integer
col_2:integer
col_3:integer
features:udt
anomalyScore:double
prediction:double
```

Comment: I have similar problem when using the Scala version.I created  the issue:https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest/issues/15

Answer (score 1):

I have just fixed this issue. It was caused by an incorrect param type. You can checkout the latest codes in the master branch, and try it again.

Comment: Thanks Yang. I'll try with new source.

Comment: Hey Yang. The new code is working fine. Thanks a lot for addressing this.